# Conforming a native class to a user-defined interface?

Tags: php, inheritance, interface

I am currently creating a library which requires the use of [OAuth](http://oauth.net/).  PHP has an [`OAuth`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php) extension, which I personally have installed and can make use of, but I don't want to require this dependency for my library, as others may not be able to use it.

I created an `OAuthInterface` interface and I'd like to just be able to implement this interface by extending the native `OAuth` class and implementing it:

```
namespace My\Lib\OAuth;

class OAuth extends \OAuth implements OAuthInterface {}
```

However, I'm having a hard time creating an interface that exactly matches the method signatures from the native `OAuth` class, and keep getting errors such as:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of OAuth::fetch() must be compatible with My\\Lib\\OAuth\\OAuthInterface::fetch($url, array $params = Array, $method = 'GET', array $headers = Array) in /path/to/My/Lib/OAuth/OAuth.php on line 7
```

Is what I'm trying to do impossible?  Will I need to make my implementation a pass-through class that compositions an instance of the native `OAuth` instead of extending it?  Or am I just not hitting on the right method signature yet?

Here is the interface, if it helps:

```
namespace My\Lib\OAuth;

interface OAuthInterface
{
    public function fetch($url, array $params = [], $method = 'GET', array $headers = []);
    public function getLastResponse();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to match the native OAuth signatures you still have kind of a dependency here because once the native OAuth class changes you will have to reflect that in your code. You could build your own interface and then use an adapter to support your own version of OAuth and the native one. [Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)

Comment: Yes, the adapter pattern is what I meant by a "pass-through class".  Thanks for the reference.